# php memcache to store repeated keys for different values

Tags: php, dictionary, memcached

I've been working with PHP (I'm very new to this) and I have this scenario:

I have a list with 3 (or more) IP addresses + ports that comes from a file, so each line of my file has:

```
192.168.3.41:8013
192.168.3.41:8023
192.168.3.41:8033
```

So in my array, these are elements `array[0], array[1], array[2]`. The purpose of the application is simple, ping the IP:PORT and know if it is responding and how many ping errors it has. But that is not all, I have to count the time it takes to do the process for 3 minutes and 1 minute. So, I've been asked to work with MemCache to do the following:

For each IP:PORT, I need to save in MemCache how many errors does I have in 3 minutes as well as the number of errors I have in 1 minute, so something like that:

For number of errors in 3 minutes

```
Map<Key, Value> = Map<IP:PORT, NumberOfErrors3Mins>
```

For number of errors in 1 minute

```
Map<Key, Value> = Map<IP:PORT, NumberOfErrors1Min>
```

So, a data sample could be like this:

For 3 minutes:

```
<192.168.3.41:8013, 5>
<192.168.3.41:8023, 2>
<192.168.3.41:8023, 0>
```

For 1 Minute:

```
<192.168.3.41:8013, 3>
<192.168.3.41:8023, 1>
<192.168.3.41:8023, 1>
```

So, I have two maps and 3 entries for each map. I'm pretty new to PHP and MemCache is kind of difficult to me, the logic I stablished is the following:

```
$array = array('192.168.3.41:8013','192.168.3.41:8023','192.168.3.41:8033');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i){
        $currentProxy = $array[$i];
        echo "working on $i : <br/>";
        echo "good to see you friend:".$currentProxy."<br/>";
        $res1 = $memt1->get($currentProxy);
        $res2 = $memt2->get($currentProxy);
        echo "response for proxy:".$res1."<br/>";
        echo "response for proxy:".$res2."<br/>";
        if (!$res1){
                echo "Does not exist - create<br/>";
                $memt1->set($currentProxy, 1, null, 0);
        } else {
                echo "Does exist - help<br/>";
                $memt1->increment($currentProxy);
        }

        if (!$res2){
                echo "Does not exist - create<br/>";
                $memt2->set($currentProxy, 1, null, 0);
        } else {
                echo "Does exist - help<br/>";
                $memt2->increment($currentProxy);
        }

}
```

The problem I am facing is that both memt1 and memt2 are referring to the same, for instance, if I increment <192.168.3.41:8013> for memt1, it also increment it for memt2, I think that this could be a very noob question, but I've just entered to PHP world and I don't know how to handle this at all, this is what I tried, if somebody could help me, please I would be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, it was simplier of what I thought before:

Basically, one MemCache for all the type of possible keys with values, I didn't know how to use it well, but now it works and fits perfect for me, hope it helps somebody who is starting with this:

```
$memHandler = new MemCache();
if ($memHandler) {
    $memHandler->connect('localhost','11211');
} else {
    die('Problem with MemCache');
}

$array1 = $memHandler->get('e1');
$array3 = $memHandler->get('e3');
$lcr1 = $memHandler->get('lcr1');
$lcr3 = $memHandler->get('lcr3');

if (!$array1) {
    echo 'Does not exist - create<br/>';
    $memHandler->set('e1', $newArray);
} else {
    echo 'Does exist<br/>';
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.':'.$value.'<br/>';
    }
}

if (!$array3) {
    echo 'Does not exist - create<br/>';
    $memHandler->set('e3', $newArray);
} else {
    echo 'Does exist<br/>';
     foreach ($array3 as $key => $value) {
             echo $key.':'.$value.'<br/>';
        }

}

echo '=============================<br/>';

if (!$lcr1){
    echo 'Does not exist - create date<br/>';
        $memHandler->set('lcr1', time());
} else {
    echo 'Does exist<br/>';
    echo $lcr1.'<br/>';
}

if (!$lcr3){ 
        echo 'Does not exist - create date<br/>';
        $memHandler->set('lcr3', time());
} else {
        echo 'Does exist<br/>';
        echo $lcr3.'<br/>';
}
```